# Why OAuth 2.0 step 5 call fail?

Tags: oauth-2.0, vapor

Using Imperial in my app for authentication. https://github.com/vapor-community/Imperial

I would implement Github auth.

This is the general sequence of OAuth 2.0 below. The problem arise, when I send a GET request to the Imperial handler with this message form `Postman`:

> http://localhost:8080/gh-auth-complete?code=1c529782861a44782488

I got back this error:

```json
{
    "error": true,
    "reason": "Value of type 'String' required for key 'access_token'."
}
```

Why? In step 5 only `code` is needed to be sent, not `access_token`. Access token is reqested and returned in step 6-7.

But!

If I call Github, and Github redirect to the endpoint: `http://127.0.0.1:8080/gh-auth-complete`

Then all goes well, completion handler will get triggered.

[image]

Comment: Because it's failing on step 7, not step 5. Breakpoint in Imperial and see what GH is returning

Comment: I see, here: `return try response.content.get(String.self, at: ["access_token"])` seems no `access_token` is returned, how is it possible?

Comment: `GITHUB_CLIENT_ID`, `GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET` are ok, message sent short after `code` was received, strange, do you have any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Where it tries to get the access token print out the body, it should say what's wrong